# Insert Multiple associative array in one doctrine native insert() command

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Is there any way, I can insert multiple associative array in database table with doctrine's native sql query execution support? Currently, I can see to insert only a single row/associative array.
code:

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$connection->insert('un_table_name', $associative_data_array);
```

My goal is to insert mutiple row in single statement so that they are inserted in single transaction.

Just to clarify, I am working on a migration task where data will be processed and transffered from old schema to new schema. but as entities are in only new schema structure, I can connect both db with ORM style. This is why I am following the native query support. also as bulk data will be transferred, I think multiple insert in single transaction will make the process faster.

Any suggestions/solutions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could employ Connection#transactional($func):

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$connection->transactional (function ($connection) {
    $connection->insert('un_table_name', $associative_data_array1);
    $connection->insert('un_table_name', $associative_data_array2);
    ...
    $connection->insert('un_table_name', $associative_data_arrayN);
});
```

Comment: You have saved my evening sir! thx :) But i have question i am getting an error $associative_data_array1 is not defined. Do i need to use global before variable or is there any other way how to pass the $associative_data_array1 to the $connection->transactional ?

Comment: You should use function with "use" keyword, as shown in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: just be careful, this approach might be slower than composing SQL insert string and and executing it